# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Gitlab WebHook

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to setup a multibranch build pipeline that will build each branch with a Jenkinsfile everytime a push occurs. I have set everything up, but the issue is that it works with only one branch. I saw a github thread that you need to use the url generated from gitlab plugins build trigger for the GitLab Webhook:

> Build when a change is pushed to Gitlab. GitLab CI Service URL: http://...

I used this but this is provides auto-triggering for only the branch I found it in.

How do I change this so that it builds this for all my branchs?

Comment: Hi Brendan, you need to use the gitlab plugin and when configuring your Jenkins project, make sure that all your branches have Jenkinsfile. Also check that your branch source settings exclude any branches. https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#webhook-url